# Is there an example of ward compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

A set $A$ is ward compact if every sequence $(a_n) $ in $A$ has a quasi-Cauchy subsequence. A sequence $(x_n)$ is said to be quasi Cauchy if $x_n-x_{n+1}\rightarrow 0$.
We know that $a_n=\sqrt n$ is a quasi sequence, what about ward compact set?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it called "ward" compact? Is it from the English word ward, or the proper name Ward, or is it a word in some other language?

Comment: At first it was forward compact then authors used ward compact.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107336/8157)

Answer (score 1):

This property is equivalent to $A$ being [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space). In the context of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is equivalent to being bounded.

Indeed, being totally bounded implies that every sequence has a Cauchy subsequence (no "quasi-" needed); see [Metric space is totally bounded iff every sequence has Cauchy subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/556150).

And if $A$ is not totally bounded, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no finite $\epsilon$-net. This makes it possible to keep choosing points at distance $\ge \epsilon$ from each other, thus forming a sequence $x_k$ for which $d(x_k, x_j)\ge \epsilon$ whenever $k\ne j$. Such a sequence has no "quasi-Cauchy" subsequence.