# Show that a metric space $(X,d)$ is totally bounded(ball compact) if and only if every sequence in X has a Cauchy subsequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

Show that a metric space $(X,d)$ is totally bounded(ball compact) if and only if every sequence in X has a Cauchy subsequence.

I already proved that if $(X,d)$ is ball compact, then every sequence in X has a Cauchy subsequence. But I have no idea how to the other part.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556150/metric-space-is-totally-bounded-iff-every-sequence-has-cauchy-subsequence

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does "ball compact" mean?